# ASP.NET Web Api in Web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, asp.net-web-api

i´m trying to use the asp.net web api in WEB FORMS with visual studio 2010 (sp1)
i have done this steps http://myrandomykien.blogspot.com/2012/02/simplest-web-api-site-with-nuget.html

When i use the visual studio development server **it works**, but when i´m using iis 7.5 i get an Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found.

**Edit**

This is my Global-asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

This is the api class

```
public class GreetingController : ApiController
{
    public string GetGreeting(string id)
    {
        return String.Format("Hello {0}", id);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide more information? not much to go on right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make sure that extensionless requests are routed to ASP.NET which is done by default by your development server but not IIS.

There are couple of possible approaches.

First, you could add `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in the modules section of the `system.webServer`. Some people claim there are better methods, you can then follow them:

http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html

Comment: If someone is using iis in Classic mode, the Wiktor's solution don´t work, you have to install the extensionLess update for iis. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368