# Problems when adding Web API to an existing ASP.NET Web Forms Application

Tags: asp.net, api, webforms, asp.net-web-api

Some background info first. I have a working website in the form of a Web Forms Application created in VS 2012 Express. Then i tried adding a Web API, by adding a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application project and selecting Web API.

So the whole project has three different projects now.

- DAL (data access layer)
- Web Forms Application
- Web API

*(I have read tutorials for adding the API to an existing project, but having the Web API in a different project is a requirement.)*

To keep it simple i am only using the controllers that are included from the start until i solve this.

My problem is that i get **404 Not Found** Errors when i try to run for example:

```
 http://localhost:49919/api/Values
```

Now i guess this is because i am trying to access the API from my site which is another project. But even after looking for hours for solutions online i couldn't find anything that solves my problem. I found some people with the same problem, but the solutions for them didn't work for me.

The things i have tried so far is:

- Added a reference to the API in the Site project.
- Adding this code to the API Web.Config. Which if understand correctly should allow access between projects.

  ```
    <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <clear/>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders  > 
  </httpProtocol  > 
  </system.webServer  >
  ```

My routing in the WebApiConfig looks like this:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Global.asax in the API looks like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

I tried making a whole new project with just a Web API and it worked without any editing.

This is my first time working with Web API, so i appreciate all the help i can get.

Edit: Thought i would add the purpose of the API. I will use it to get the latest messages from DAL and show it with jQuery/AJAX on the site.

Edit2: Changed the IIS port on the API to the same one as my website.

Website `http://localhost:49919/`

API `http://localhost:49919/api/(/api because they can't have the same url)`

The links look like this now 49919/api/api/values, but that can be fixed.

Ofcourse it was something as simple as that, but i had no idea that needed to be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536362/asp-net-web-api-in-web-forms

Comment: I have tried the "<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />" solution and it didn't do anything. I dont think his scenario is the same as mine.

Comment: I believe the default route template for webapi **doesn't** contain `{action}`. Consult the docs.

Comment: You are right, i changed that in the beginning. One of the included urls will look like this, http://localhost:49919/api/Values/GET/5. {action} is there to declare for example GET. Changing it back didn't do anything unfortunately, since my errors are coming even when trying to access just api/Values.

Comment: @EdoBhc, could you ever solve this issue? I have exactly the same problem and Wiktor's solution didn't work for me either. I think the only difference is that you're running MVC4 while I'm running MVC5. Thanks for an answer! :)

Comment: @LuisGouveia Yes, like i wrote in the edit i changed the IIS port in the settings for the api project so it was the same as the main project. That solved it for me. Sorry for taking so long to respond, didnt see your post before now. Good luck!

Comment: Hello @EdoBhc. You can anwser your own question and accept it.
I think this can help users. :)
Regards.

Comment: @EdoBhc Great! And lets keep on learning. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i used for my problem:

I changed the IIS port on the API project to the same one as my website project.

Website http://localhost:49919/

API http://localhost:49919/api/

( /api because they can't have the same url )

The links look like this now 49919/api/api/values, but that can be fixed.