# Is it possible to run web api in IIS classic mode app pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Because of my production server limitation, I need to deploy my application in a IIS classic mode app pool. Just wondering, if it possible to run web api in IIS classic mode app pool?

Comment: An old document, but this may contain the information that you are looking for: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Web Api in Web forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536362/asp-net-web-api-in-web-forms)

Comment: Excerpt from link's comment above.  "If someone is using iis in Classic mode, you have to install the extensionLess update for iis. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368 "

Comment: Why don't you try it and, if you find some problem, make a concrete question?

Comment: I have a working web api on my dev server in "integrated mode", but whe deployed it didn't work.  I came to know about this limitation only after  deploying to production and was told that I cannot use "Integrated Mode".  I will try and see if the above solution works. If anybody already made it work, please let me know.